# Can the interface method with default implementation be implemented implicitly in a class?

Tags: c#, default-implementation

Just the code:

```cs
public interface ICalculator
{
    public double Calculate(double x) => x + 5;
}

public class Calculator: ICalculator
{
}

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();
        Console.WriteLine("Calculate(2) = {0}", calculator.Calculate(2));
    }
}
```

It works fine becuse the `Calculate` method is implemented explicitly. The `calculator` has the `ICalculator` type, so everything is ok. But if I'll change the type of the `calculator` to the `Calculator`, I'll get error:

```cs
        // Was: ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        Console.WriteLine("Calculate(2) = {0}", calculator.Calculate(2));
```

> [CS1061] "Calculator" does not contain a definition for "Calculate" and no accessible extension method "Calculate" accepting a first argument of type "Calculator" could be found (are you missing a using directive of an assembly reference?).

I understand that it's beacuase the `Calculate` method is implemented explicitly in the class, so

```cs
public class Calculator: ICalculator
{
}
```

really means:

```cs
public class Calculator: ICalculator
{
    double ICalculator.Calculate(double x) => x + 5;
}
```

I'm just wondering if the class can have an implicit implementation of such a method? I couldn't google the answer.

Comment: as far as I know , no can't do it , but you can try use abstract class.

Comment: If you take a look at the IL code, you will find the method is implemented in the interface, the implementation in the class doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In such these scenarios I always use a base abstract class like this:

```cs
public interface ICalculator
{
    double Calculate(double x);
}

public abstract class BaseCalculator : ICalculator
{
    public virtual double Calculate(double x) => x + 5;
}

public class Calculator : BaseCalculator { }
```

And this code will be fine:

```cs
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
Console.WriteLine("Calculate(2) = {0}", calculator.Calculate(2));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's interesting to know about the interfaces exactly, because abstract classes have been behaving this way since C# 1.0.